# C: Initialize struct with constant sub-struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have a single instantiation of a struct called `single_instance`. This instance contains constants objects of type `struct example_type`.

```c
typedef struct {
  int n;
} example_type;

struct {
  int some_variables;
  // ...
  const example_type t1;
  const example_type t2;
  // ...
} single_instance;
```

Let's say that I want to init `single_instance.t1` to `{1}` and `single_instance.t2` to `{2}`.

**What is the most elegant way to do so?**

Inline initialization is not possible:

```c
struct {
  int some_variables;
  // ...
  const example_type t1 = {1};
  const example_type t2 = {2};
  // ...
} single_instance;
```

This doesn't work too:

```c
struct {
  int some_variables;
  // ...
  const example_type t1;
  const example_type t2;
  // ...
} single_instance {0, {0}, {1}};
```

I have read multiple other threads related to this topic, however it seems that they all refer to initialize structs with "a name".  In this case I want just one instantiation of `single_instance`, as such the type should not have a name.

Comment: The last one works. You just forgot the `=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *designated initializers* to explicitly initialize the members you are interested in. The remaining members will then be implicitly initialized to 0.

```
struct {
  int some_variables;
  // ...
  const example_type t1;
  const example_type t2;
  // ...
} single_instance = {.t1 = {1}, .t2 = {2}};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (maybe You're just missing `=` in initialization):

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int n;
} example_type;

struct {
  int some_variables;
  // ...
  const example_type t1;
  const example_type t2;
  // ...
} single_instance = {0, {1}, {2}};

int main() {

    printf("%d %d %d\n", single_instance.some_variables, single_instance.t1.n, single_instance.t2.n);
}
```